# How to install ubuntu in a windows 7 operating system

Tags: dual-boot

Pls explain in detail. I am downloading x63 iso file..

Pls tell me all the steps after i download this file

Comment: I am having a windows 7 platform and i am finding that there r lots of viruses in my lap. Therefore, i am planning to install ubuntu along with windows and then slowly format the windows completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download and install an iso burner, such as [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/)
- Burn your downloaded iso onto a DVD-RW
- Restart your computer and boot from the DVD
- Follow the installation steps on the Ubuntu Installer
- Select the option that is something like **Install alongside Windows** - it will partition your disk, allocation one part to Windows and one to Ubuntu
- Once the installation has completed, reboot your computer and remove the disk.

Tadaa! You now have Ubuntu installed alongside Linux. You can choose whether to boot into Linux or Windows once your PC has started.

Comment: Is it possible that we copy the iso file into our pendrive and then boot it from Pendrive after restarting?

Comment: @VipinNair yes, you can use this: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There are two ways you can go about installing Ubuntu "in a windows 7 operating system." It depends on what you want, which was hard to determine with the information you posted. You can install in a virtual machine which runs inside of Windows, or you can partition your hard drive and boot into Ubuntu. Which were you trying to do?</strike>

Installing Ubuntu is pretty simple. Yay!

You need to download a USB image writer. Such as this one:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

You're also going to need a USB flash drive.

Once you've got that downloaded, go ahead and run it as well as plug in your flash drive. Select your .iso that you already have downloaded. Then select your flash drive and make sure you select to format(This is gonna erase everything from your flash drive so make sure you save everything you have on there somewhere else). Then hit create and it'll write the .iso to your flash drive.

After you have a bootable flash drive, boot into it. Shutdown your computer, plug in your flash drive, and then power on.  Hit the key for one-time-boot options (F12 for Dell, F9 for HP, blah blah, google it if you can't find out how). Select USB boot in the boot options and then it'll boot into Ubuntu.

Once you've booted into Ubuntu you have two options, try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu. If you want to install alongside Windows you're safe to hit install. It'll give you an option to install along side an operating system. Go through the installer and bam.

I do this daily, I'm a computer technician and we use Linux on our machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.2 desktop-amd64.iso.

Is it possible that we copy the iso file into our pendrive and then boot it from Pendrive after restarting?

If yes, could you please provide me with the steps for that.

To be frank, I am not good with the computers

Comment: Ask this as a new question - or edit your previous one